# Reusing AndroidTV RowsFragment outside BrowseFragment

Tags: android, android-tv, leanback

I'm trying to reuse the RowsFragment provided by AndroidTV Leanback outside of a BrowseFragment, to have a similar row interaction look & feel on a different layout, but I'm getting XML-inflation errors that I haven't been able to debug and solve.

The implementation itself is similar to what is implemented here: https://medium.com/building-for-android-tv , but in the blog he's replacing different fragments of the same kind inside a BrowseFragment. Is there something fundamentally wrong with my approach? If so, why? I've been reading through the Leanback sources and haven't been able to find anything that I would understand (although it's a large library) that would couple the fragments to that degree.

A reproduction of the relevant code:
https://gist.github.com/orbitbot/c9070ed00961c3abe4ca

```
02-26 12:12:26.950    4465-4527/com.my.client E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
      Process: com.my.client, PID: 4465
      android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class <unknown>
              at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
              at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
              at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:462)
              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
              at android.support.v17.leanback.widget.RowContainerView.<init>(RowContainerView.java:48)
              at android.support.v17.leanback.widget.RowContainerView.<init>(RowContainerView.java:37)
              at android.support.v17.leanback.widget.RowPresenter.onCreateViewHolder(RowPresenter.java:169)
              at android.support.v17.leanback.widget.ItemBridgeAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(ItemBridgeAdapter.java:247)
              at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:4121)
              at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:3431)
              at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:3340)
              at android.support.v17.leanback.widget.GridLayoutManager.getViewForPosition(GridLayoutManager.java:573)
              at android.support.v17.leanback.widget.GridLayoutManager$2.createItem(GridLayoutManager.java:1057)
              at android.support.v17.leanback.widget.StaggeredGrid.appendItemToRow(StaggeredGrid.java:242)
              at android.support.v17.leanback.widget.StaggeredGridDefault.appendItems(StaggeredGridDefault.java:49)
              at android.support.v17.leanback.widget.GridLayoutManager.appendOneVisibleItem(GridLayoutManager.java:1263)
              at android.support.v17.leanback.widget.GridLayoutManager.appendVisibleItems(GridLayoutManager.java:1273)
              at android.support.v17.leanback.widget.GridLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(GridLayoutManager.java:1554)
              at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:1988)
              at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:2237)
              at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
              at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
              at android.support.v17.leanback.widget.ScaleFrameLayout.onLayout(ScaleFrameLayout.java:135)
              at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
              at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
              at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
              at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
              at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
              at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
              at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
              at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
              at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
              at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
              at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
              at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
              at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
              at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
              at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
              at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
              at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
              at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
              at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
              at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
              at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
              at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
              at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
              at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
              at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1989)
              at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1746)
              at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
              at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5672)
              at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:772
```

Comment: I'm the author of that series of articles. It's not so clear to me what you're trying to achieve and how it differs from what I've done with the custom BrowseFragment implementation.

Comment: OK, got it. It does look right at a first glance. I'm going to give it a spin and see if I can understand what's going on.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the effort! I'm about to add more fragments to the layout later, so the RowsFragment would only be a part of it (approximately a lower half).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that your **ChangePicActivity** has proper theme in AndroidManifest.xml

Add **android:theme="@style/Theme.Leanback"** to relevant **activity** tag.
Like this

> ```
>  <activity
>         android:name=".ChangePicActivity"
>         android:theme="@style/Theme.Leanback"
>  >
> [...]
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Obvious when you realize it, but we we're messing with the themes on a per-activity basis because of legacy reasons.